Как проверить строку на наличие в ней букв?
Пишу код на GAS, который предусматривает ввод данных пользователем. Мне нужно получить строку и проверить её на предмет правильного заполнения. К примеру, в строке должны содержаться данные в формате даты, а пользователь вводит туда текст. На этом моменте скрипт должен перестать работать и выдать пользователю сообщение о неверно введённых данных.
Ввод данных пользователем реализовала через Ui.
UPD: вызываю окно для ввода данных следующим образом:
var data=ui.prompt("Укажите плановую дату начал работ:").
Теперь нужно проверить переменную на наличие в ней букв.
var spreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()
var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi() //подключаем взаимодействие с пользователем
var title=ui.prompt("Введите название двигателя:")
//вызываем окно ввода названия двигателя
var executor=ui.prompt("Укажите исполнителя:")
//вызываем окно ввода фамилии исполнителя
var data=ui.prompt("Укажите плановую дату начал работ:")


Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

@BorisBaublys, дополнила вопрос

Невоспроизводимый пример - ui не определён.

@BorisBaublys, var spreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()
var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi() //подключаем взаимодействие с пользователем
var title=ui.prompt("Введите название двигателя:") //вызываем оено ввода названия двигателя
var executor=ui.prompt("Укажите исполнителя:") //вызываем окно ввода фамилии исполнителя
var data=ui.prompt("Укажите плановую дату начал работ:")

Код, приведённый ниже, ищет в пользовательском вводе буквы латиницы и кириллицы. Если находит хотя бы одну, выводит сообщение.
function getPrompt() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const data = ui.prompt("Укажите плановую дату начала работ:");
  if (data.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    const responseText = data.getResponseText();
    const isLetter = /[A-ZА-ЯЁ]+/i.test(responseText);
    if (isLetter) ui.alert('Неверно введены данные.');
  }
}


К регистру чувствительна функция?
